# Edit content stored into a Data Extension when journey is active

Tags: dataextensions

I launched a dynamic email this morning but the client notice a typo error in the content.
The copy is stored in a Data Extension (that is not my entry source) and I do a lookup in my email.
Can I pause the journey, import the new copy into my DE and then resume the journey? Or should I create a new version and it would work?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pause the Journey, update the data extension and update the email activity in the Journey by following the steps mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5).... You don't have to create a new version for this change.